# Unreachable Error with dragging and zooming images

Tags: java, android

```
public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent)
  {
    ImageView localImageView = (ImageView)paramView;
    dumpEvent(paramMotionEvent);
    switch (0xFF & paramMotionEvent.getAction())
    {
    }
    for (;;)
    {
      localImageView.setImageMatrix(this.matrix);
      return true;
      this.savedMatrix.set(this.matrix)
      this.start.set(paramMotionEvent.getX(), paramMotionEvent.getY());
      Log.d("Touch", "mode=DRAG");
      this.mode = 1;
      continue;
      this.oldDist = spacing(paramMotionEvent);
      Log.d("Touch", "oldDist=" + this.oldDist);
      if (this.oldDist > 10.0F)
      {
        this.savedMatrix.set(this.matrix);
        midPoint(this.mid, paramMotionEvent);
        this.mode = 2;
        Log.d("Touch", "mode=ZOOM");
        continue;
        this.mode = 0;
        Log.d("Touch", "mode=NONE");
        continue;
        if (this.mode == 1)
        {
          this.matrix.set(this.savedMatrix);
          this.matrix.postTranslate(paramMotionEvent.getX() - this.start.x, paramMotionEvent.getY() - this.start.y);
        }
        else if (this.mode == 2)
        {
          float f1 = spacing(paramMotionEvent);
          Log.d("Touch", "newDist=" + f1);
          if (f1 > 10.0F)
          {
            this.matrix.set(this.savedMatrix);
            float f2 = f1 / this.oldDist;
            this.matrix.postScale(f2, f2, this.mid.x, this.mid.y);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using the matrix method to be able to scroll and zoom images in the app.

However, I'm getting the error **Unreachable code**, in the part(the first time this statement appears)
`this.savedMatrix.set(this.matrix)`

Any suggestions? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

because of this line..

```
return true;
```

You are returning the value..without performing any operation..so the code below your return statement is not execute any more..

so add this at the bottom of the method..

```
return true;
```

Comment: So should I get rid of return true; and continue;? is the return true; necessary?

Comment: @user3131565 yes it is necessary..because this method must return boolean value..add this line at the end of method..above the last } closng paranthesis